# Jeditable Not Returning "id" Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, jeditable

I can't seem to get the proper return of "id" from my Jeditable function.

Code looks like this:

```
<li id="249" rel="4">
    <span title="Double-click to edit...">EDIT THIS TEXT</span>
<div class="tab"></div>
</li>
```

I call the jeditable function like so:

```
bindAllTabs("#list li span");

    function bindAllTabs(editableTarget) {

    $(editableTarget).editable("db-interaction/lists.php", {
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip   : 'Double-click to edit...',
        event     : 'dblclick',
        submit    : 'Save',
        submitdata: {action : "update"}

    });
```

How can I send the "id" from the parent? 
I need to keep them separate since I have other s listed below the editable text -- so I'm using the  as an identifier. However, since I've put the ID in the parent I can't seem to access it with jeditable.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution

```
function bindAllTabs(editableTarget) {

        $(editableTarget).editable("db-interaction/lists.php", {
            indicator : 'Saving...',
            tooltip   : 'Double-click to edit...',
            event     : 'dblclick',
            submit    : 'Save',
            submitdata: function( value, settings){
              var parent_id = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
              return { action : 'update', id : parent_id};  
            }

        }); 

    }
```